# Gram Schmidt implementation works partially, outputs a bad number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement Gram Schmidt in code for a school project and I have a problem.It outputs a weird number and I don't know why.The rest of them are good but this one is bad.Sorry if the post is bad but it's my first post here and I really need help.Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#define dim 100

using namespace std;



void inputMatrix(int *n, int *m, double x[dim][dim]){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < *n; i++){
        cout << "V" << i << ":";
        for(j = 0; j < *m; j++)
            cin >> x[i][j];
    }

}

void outputMatrix(int *n, int *m, double x[dim][dim]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<*n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<*m;j++)
            cout<<x[i][j]<<"  ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void initialize(int *m,double v[dim]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<*m;i++){
         v[i]=0;
    }    
}
int main(){
    double v[dim][dim], f[dim][dim], e[dim][dim],p1,p2,a[dim];
    int n,m,i,j,z;
    cout << "Introduceti numarul de vectori: ";cin >> n;
    cout << "Introduceti numarul de elemente: ";cin >> m;
    inputMatrix(&n,&m,v);
    double div = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        f[0][i] = v[0][i];
    }
    outputMatrix(&n,&m,v);
    cout << endl;
    outputMatrix(&n,&m,f);
    for(i = 1;i < n; i++){
        z = 0;
        initialize(&m,a);
        mk1:
        p1 = 0;
        p2 = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            p1 = f[z][j] * v[i][j] + p1;
            p2 = f[z][j] * f[z][j] + p2;
        }
        div = p1 / p2;
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            a[j] = f[z][j] * div + a[j];
        }
        z++;
        if( z < i){
            goto mk1;
        }
        else{
            for(j = 0; j < m;j++){
                f[i][j] = v[i][j] - a[j];
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    outputMatrix(&n,&m,f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Introduceti numarul de vectori: 3
Introduceti numarul de elemente: 4
V0:1
2
3
0
V1:1
2
0
0
V2:1
0
0
1
1  2  3  0  
1  2  0  0  
1  0  0  1  

1  2  3  0  
0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  

1  2  3  0  
0.642857  1.28571  -1.07143  0  
0.8  -0.4  5.55112e-17  1
```

I don't understand why it outputs this "5.55112e-17"
Thanks for help!

Comment: 5.55112e-17 is, for all intents and purposes, 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the correct output should be 0 there, so that's an  artifact of calculating, but it can be resolved ?

Comment: Instead of `#define dim 100`, use a const, i.e., `const int dim_matrix = 100`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why it outputs this "5.55112e-17" Thanks for help!

This is the result of rounding errors, this notation means 5.55112 times 10 to the power of -17 and can be considered an artifact of calculating with computer representations of (real) numbers. For some more elaboration, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) answer.

Comment: I understand the problem here, the thing is that it should output 0 instead of that, it is possible somehow to fix it ?

Comment: @ViorelAndreiChis Of course you could just purge every number below a certain threshold to be zero: `if(abs(n) < 1.e-14) n = 0.;` This might produce exact results here, but may be problematic for problem where e.g. the vectors are near linear dependent.

Comment: Thanks for help, now it works just fine, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

`5.55112e-17` is very close to zero. It is  not exactly zero, due to the numerical resolution of your used binary representation of numbers (e.g. `double`).

You can use a higher resolution for the calculation than for the printing of the results.
Alternatively, you can round at the end. Nevertheless, you can not get rid of the numerics.

Here a few other remarks on your code:

- Please use proper containers, here `std::vector`. This also enables you to use dynamic memory allocation (Your code will crash if the matrix becomes bigger than 100).
- Please dont use `goto`. Below you find an alternative implementation.
- It is not meaningful to hand pointers to integers to a function. You don't gain anything from that, but the readability is reduced.

Code without `goto`

```
int main() {
    double v[dim][dim], f[dim][dim], e[dim][dim], p1, p2, a[dim];
    int n, m, i, j, z;
    cout << "Introduceti numarul de vectori: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Introduceti numarul de elemente: ";
    cin >> m;
    inputMatrix(&n, &m, v);
    double div = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        f[0][i] = v[0][i];
    }
    outputMatrix(&n, &m, v);
    cout << endl;
    outputMatrix(&n, &m, f);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        z = 0;
        initialize(&m, a);
        do {
            p1 = 0;
            p2 = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                p1 = f[z][j] * v[i][j] + p1;
                p2 = f[z][j] * f[z][j] + p2;
            }
            div = p1 / p2;
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                a[j] = f[z][j] * div + a[j];
            }
            z++;
        } while (z < i);
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            f[i][j] = v[i][j] - a[j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    outputMatrix(&n, &m, f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For matrices I would not make use `std::vector` at all: matrices are not resizeable. I agree on the dynamic memory part, though. Using a matrix with a memory size close to the number of elements will benefit the processor's cache performance of the program.